# Parallel Execution is not working in testng.xml.it is executing only last test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Please find the Testng.xml and the Test Script

```
My Script:
@Parameters("browserName")
@BeforeMethod   
public void setupApp(String browserName) {
    driver=BrowsersFactory.startApplication(driver, browserName, config.getQaUrl());
}
```

Comment: Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In parallel execution, you need to set the parallel parameter in the xml file.

> parallel="true"

```
<test name="Basic validation" parallel="true"  thread-count="8">
    <classes>
         <class name="Pages.Scenarios.AccumulationTestCases"/>
        <class name="Pages.Scenarios.ScenarioTestCases"/>
        <class name="Pages.Scenarios.AlertScenarios"/>
        <class name="Pages.Alert.AlertTestCases"/>
        <class name="Pages.Scenarios.DummyTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

if you remove thread-count="8", TestNG will automatically calculate the thread count based on your core/thread of machine.